# How to change the provisioning profile of a borrowed code?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

A Youtuber put his code online and gave permission for anyone to use it. I downloaded the code and am trying to put it on my iOS device; however, an error pops up when that happens. It says...

'No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the bundle identifier “com.mymobilerobots.openCViOSFaceTrackingTutorial” were found.'

How do I change the thing I need to change in order to put it on my phone. Sorry for my poor wording and my lack of knowledge. Thank you

Comment: I change the bundle identifier to my proper bundle identifier, but an error then appears...

"Linker command failed with exit code 1"

Comment: Since you solved the original issue you should delete this question. If you are now stuck with a new problem building the app, post a new question with relevant details.

Comment: @rmaddy It seems that the "Linker command failed..." error is very common and can relate to a various different problems so I do not think it should be the focus of the question. I took a step in what I hope is the right direction and we should keep on moving that way

Comment: But people looking for your issue should know that the solution to using another person's project on a device is to ensure that you have changed the bundle id to match your own. Now that you have another problem, it is best to create a new question with the details of your linker error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-sign the binary using one of your own certificates.

Scripts like [ipa-resigner](https://github.com/bq/ipa-resigner) make this easy.